# Trying to parse JSON in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension, where I need to parse some JSON, and display it in the popup (for testing purposes, I will use it later). I can't even get that part to work. I've looked at the JS console, and the popup inspector, I don't see any errors. The problem will become a little clearer when you see the code:

The code in `popup.html` and `manifest.json` is here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVjJZ/)

I should be seeing the `output` variable in the console, and in the HTML div, or see some errors when I inspect `popup.html`. I see none of those, so I don't understand whats going on at all. Does someone see why?

Answer (score 0):

You have

`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('map');`

instead of

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(map);
```

You should also declare variables before using them: `for( var property in map )` instead of `for( property in map )`

jsfiddle is failing because you are calling functions that don't exist in web page context:
http://jsfiddle.net/bVjJZ/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed both of those issues, but I still get no output.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extension sandbox security policy prevent your execution of parseJSON (or in plain Javascript, eval).

I currently pass around this issue by using my own message format and parser...